# Universal property of the homotopy limit/colimit.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, limits-colimits

I have been trying to find a reference for what I have heard is a universal property which defines homotopy limits and colimits.

In the category **Top**, colimits can be defined using the following universal property:

> Let $\mathcal{F}:\mathcal{D} \rightarrow \textbf{Top}$ be a diagram of shape $\mathcal{D}$ in **Top**. The colimit of $\mathcal{F}$ is defined to be an object $O$ together with maps $\phi_d$ for every object $d \in \mathcal{D}$ (such that everything commutes) such that if there is another co-cone under the diagram with tip $Z$ (and maps ${\psi_d}$ such that everything commutes), then there is a unique map $\Phi:O \rightarrow Z$ making everything commute.

There is a similar universal property for the limit of $\mathcal{F}$.

I'm hoping to find a universal property along these lines which the homotopy colimit satisfies. What I initially thought was that we could simply use the universal property which the colimit satisfies, except change the category from **Top** to **HoTop** (where Hotop is the category with spaces for objects and homotopy *classes* of maps for morphisms).

This doesn't seem to be satisfied by what I know to be examples of the homotopy colimit of a diagram, though.

For example, given the diagram which sends $S^1$ into two distinct copies of the disk $D^2$, the homotopy colimit "is" $S^2$. Then there are at least two distinct morphisms in **HoTop** $S^2 \rightarrow S^2$ (i.e. two distinct homotopy classes of maps) which make everything commute up to homotopy.

Is there (alternatively) a universal property of the homotopy colimit which says:

> Let $\mathcal{F}:\mathcal{D} \rightarrow \textbf{HoTop}$ be a diagram of shape $\mathcal{D}$ in **HoTop**. The colimit of $\mathcal{F}$ is defined to be an object $O$ together with morphisms $\phi_d$ for every object $d \in \mathcal{D}$ (such that everything commutes) such that if there is another co-cone under the diagram with tip $Z$ (and morphisms ${\psi_d}$ such that everything commutes), then there is a (not necessarily unique) morphism $\Phi:O \rightarrow Z$ making everything commute.

Commutativity in the homotopy category being homotopy commutativity in **Top**, and morphisms being homotopy classes of morphisms in **Top**

If not, is there anything like that? Is the simplest bet otherwise to go with "an object which is homotopy equivalent to a specific construction of the homotopy colimit"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under a suitable framework, homotopy colimits and limits satisfy a "local homotopical universal property".  For example, homotopy colimits represent "homotopy coherent cones".  See section 10 of Shulman's "Homotopy limits and colimits and enriched homotopy theory" for the definitions and a discussion.  Riehl's *Categorical homotopy theory* also discusses this in section 7.7.

Homotopy colimits and limits also have a global definition in terms of derived functors when they make sense.  So this could also serve as an universal property defining them.

Comment: And so in this case, could one use the universal property (for colimits) which I state above? I.E. The homotopy colimit of a diagram $\mathcal{F}$ is a co-cone $Z$ where for any other co-cone $\overline{Z}$ there exists a homotopy coherent map $f:Z \rightarrow \overline{Z}$?

Comment: I don't think so.  Your proposed universal property only asks for homotopy commutativity, but homotopy coherence is much more structure.  In fact, your definition sort of looks like a colimit in the homotopy category, but in general those often fail to exist.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your informative answer :)